# Is it possible to use Google Protocol Buffers 2.6.1 with C#?

Tags: c#, protobuf-net, protocol-buffers, protobuf-csharp-port

I have a project where I am using Google Protocol Buffers 2.6.1 for about two years now. I know that C# is supported in Google Protocol Buffers 3.0.0, but I don't want to migrate my protocol to a newer version at the moment. I tried to find a way to generate C# files from my .proto file but I didn't succeed.

**Is it possible to use Google Protocol Buffers 2.6.1 with C#?**

Answer (score 1):

Check out [this repo](https://github.com/jskeet/protobuf-csharp-port).

It states:

> This repo was originally exported from http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-csharp-port, and represents the latest "legacy" version of protobuf-csharp-port.
>
> This project has now been folded into the main Google Protocol Buffers project, and is being revamped to support proto3. It is not expected to be fully backwardly-compatible with the code in this repo - in particular, some of the C#-specific options may not be supported in the new codebase, and some of the generated code may differ. A new major version offers an opportunity to spring-clean, as it were.

Comment: I tried that already and it didn't work. I downloaded latest relase. Tried to use protoc.exe located in \protobuf-csharp-port-2.4.1.555\lib\protoc.exe but it doesn't support C# therefore I couldn't generate C# wrpappers for my 2.6.1 based protocol definition which is my goal.

Answer (score 1):

In `~\protobuf-csharp-port-2.4.1.555\src\ProtoGen\ProtocGenCs.cs` You've got example in comment:

```
// Usage example:
//   protoc.exe
//     --plugin=path\to\protoc-gen-cs.exe
//     --cs_out="-generated_code_attributes=true umbrella_namespace=TutorialProto :."
//     --proto_path=.\protos\
//     protos\tutorial\addressbook.proto
```

Answer (score 0):

I have been consuming [this repo](https://github.com/maingi4/ProtoBuf.Services) 
It is based on protobuf protocol. Works well on production version of our product.

Comment: Thanks, but I need protoc.exe compiler which will be able to generate for me C# wrappers from my protocol definition (.proto file) which is complainant with 2.6.1 version of Google Protocol Buffers. Your answer is not a solution for my issue.

Answer (score 0):

The Google C# implementation supports proto3; protobuf-net supports both proto2 and proto3. So if you need proto2 usage, you may wish to consider protobuf-net.